# How to define a static table of strings in iPhone / XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, static, nsdictionary

I want a table of state-names for debug/trace messages as I develop my custom gesture.  What is wrong with this declaration and its usage?

```
static NSDictionary *dictStateNames = nil;

@implementation MyCustomGesture


@synthesize state;

+(void)initStateNames {
    if (dictStateNames == nil) {
        dictStateNames = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"StateBegan", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan],
                          @"StateCancelled", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled],
                          @"StateChanged", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged],
                          @"StateEnded", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded],
                          @"StateFailed", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed],
                          @"StatePossible", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible],
                          @"StateRecognized", [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized],
                          nil];
    }
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [MyCustomGesture initStateNames];
        state = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];
    if (self) {
        [MyCustomGesture initStateNames];
        state = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible;
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*) stateName: (UIGestureRecognizerState) state {
    NSString *retName = [dictStateNames objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:state]];
    if (retName == nil) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unknown state (%@)", state];
    } else {
        return retName;
    }
}

-(NSString*) currentStateName {
    return [MyCustomGesture stateName:state];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%s (%@): %@", __FUNCTION__, [self currentStateName], event);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you store a reference to an object in a static variable, you need to ensure that it doesn't get deallocated. So you can either send it a `retain` message, or create with `alloc` instead of a convenience creation method. For example:

```
    dictStateNames = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      // List of objects and keys...
                      nil] retain];
```

or this...

```
    dictStateNames = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      // List of objects and keys...
                      nil];
```

Also, you can coalesce your `stateNames` getter and the initialization code into a single method, so you'll typically see Objective-C developers write a method like this:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)stateNames
{
    static NSDictionary *stateNames;

    if (stateNames == nil) {
        stateNames = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      // List of objects and keys...
                      nil];
    }

    return stateNames;
}
```

That way, there's no need to call it in an instance method (which would be wrong anyway, since a new dictionary would be created each time an instance is initialized, and unless you handled it differently, the previous one would be leaked).

On another (unrelated) note, consider rewriting your `init` method as follows:

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithTarget:nil action:NULL];
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The problem with your code, mobibob, as jlehr, says, is that it's being dealloc'd. If you retain it properly it will solve your issue.

Comment: Now that makes sense.  I knew it was fundamentally wrong, but I could not determine where the pointer was "going bad" (deallocated).  BTW - I already moved the code to initialize inside the getter function as you suggest, now to coalesce with the init as you suggest.  It is all recoded with your suggestions and it works correctly and does not crash.

Comment: Why does `stateNames` return `void` rather than `NSDictionary*`?

Answer (score 3):

`[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys]` takes an object first followed by its key (as the method name suggests), which seems a bit backward but there it is.

Comment: I have a feeling I'd like Objective-C a bit more if it weren't for how mindbending the API is. You'd think something with lots of verbosity would be easy to understand, but it's almost _too_ verbose and repetitive (as a simple example, `NSNumber numberWithInt:` rather than, say, `NSNumber fromInt:` or `NSNumber withInt:`), and in many cases weirdly convoluted (but that's a topic for a different discussion).

Comment: Generic method names in different classes are not a great idea unless they happen to behave the same for the different classes. The selectors (method names) live in a global namespace in certain regards.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear with my question and description.  I understand the NSDictionary and these discussed methods, but what I am asking about is the scope of storage and reference.  My code works as expected for "touchesBegan", but crashes on the "touchesMoved" trying to access the dictionary.  Is there a better (proper) way to declare a dictionary that is static and referenced by all instances of MyCustomGesture.  Note that in the NSLog, I want to lookup the name of the current-state and display it as a string from the dictionary.